# Router.go() does not trigger rendered

Tags: collections, meteor, rendering, iron-router

Let's say I have a template called "home":

```
<template name="home">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</template>
```

And I give it a rendered event:

```
Template.home.rendered = function () {
  alert('Hello!');
};
```

And a "home" route:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/'
  });
});
```

Now, when I first load the page the "Hello!" alert comes correctly. But then, no matter how much I type `Router.go('home')` in the console, the alert from the `rendered` callback does not trigger anymore...

How would I go about writing something that triggers each time there is a Router.go(), but after the template is fully rendered, (specifically, a listing of a collection that may vary), as I want to apply jquery every time to a new set of collection elements?

Comment: Are you calling `Router.go('home')` while already on the `home` route?

Comment: That is very correct sir.

Comment: That would be why it is not being re-rendered, try creating another route and then switch between them and you should see it work.

Comment: Sadly this is the only way I found, I could not find a "refresh" method... Should I resort to do a Router.go() towards a dummy route that just redirects back to my home template? That sounds like a terrible hack.

Comment: As for your second question take a look at the after hooks in Iron-Router: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#before-and-after-hooks

Comment: What is it you are trying to do, as it sounds like there might be a better way?

Comment: My home page shows a list of items, and has a sidebar with a selector on it that changes the filter for the items on the home page. Then the list is correctly refreshed (without a router.go) but I want to rerun a jquery bit on the newly generated set every time the selector value is changed.

Comment: So why not run the jQuery function on the selector change event?

Comment: That was an idea. I tried to put my jquery in the callback of my method call. An alert does get triggered, but the jquery does not apply to the newly generated elements. My guess is that the jquery runs before the list is fully rendered. Only way I managed to get it to work so far, was by creating a subtemplate for each element, and put my jquery in the rendered event of that template. But it's also a terrible hack, as the code will then run as many times as there are elements in the list.

Comment: Hmm I see. Can you edit the question with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to apply jquery on a collection of elements it's probably better if you use Meteor.defer().
[snippet explaining the usage](http://pastebin.com/zUN38xN6)

Anyway, I found no way to trigger the .rendered() function while not changing route.
This blows when a route have parameters and you use Router.go() to redirect to the new parameter (example /page/2).
I solved that issue with a terrible hack like:

```
<span style="display:none;">{{fakeHelper}}</span>
```

And then insert the code in the fakeHelper helper function.
Horrible, but it worked for me in that situation.

Comment: Yep ! Meteor.defer() did the trick. It waits for whatever is being updated on the DOM before calling the callback, so I use it after each "view altering" action and the jQuery called in it acts correctly every time. Turns out my problem was more about a changing reactive content than a Router issue... Many thanks to Mr D for his precious help.